# Deb Package Templates File Variables

Tags: debian, deb, debconf

I am building a .deb package which will install software to create a RAID array from prexisting system devices. I would like to have a question presented to the user through the templates file, using the multiselect type to choose their devices.

How would I go about referencing an array variable in the templates file?

```
Template: raid/question4
Title: RAID Devices
Type: multiselect
Default: ${devices[@]}
Description: Select devices to include in RAID array.
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an old thread which answers my question, looks like the proper way to do this is with db_subst: [here](https://lists.debian.org/debian-boot/2010/02/msg00766.html)